# VARCHAR2 as Number in Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to load this native SQL sentence (which corresponds to the application of the Haversine formula to get a distance from given latitude and longitude) through Hibernate 4.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT e2.*, t.distance FROM entity e2 inner join 
    (SELECT 3956 * 2 * ASIN( SQRT( POWER(SIN(( :lat - abs(e.latitude)) * 3.14159/180 / 2),2) 
    + COS( :lat * 3.14159/180 ) * COS(abs(e.latitude) *  3.14159/180) 
    * POWER(SIN((:lon - e.longitude) *  3.14159/180 / 2),2) ) ) * 1.609344 as distance, e.id  
    FROM entity e ) t on  t.id = e2.id WHERE TO_NUMBER(distance) < TO_NUMBER(:maxDistance) ORDER BY distance) WHERE rowNum < 30
```

The problem is, latitude and longitude are stored as `VARCHAR2` (for whatever reason) and I cannot change the data model.

Yet if I run this through my SQL manager application this works out of the box, however in Hibernate it seems it's having some problems with the `VARCHAR2` to `NUMBER` conversion and I get an Invalid Number error in SQL. I tried to force the conversion by using `TO_NUMBER(e.latitude)` but it does not achieve anything.

PD: I actually tried this (with no parameters):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT e2.*, t.distance FROM estaciones e2 inner join 
        (SELECT 3956 * 2 * ASIN(
                                SQRT( 
                                    POWER(SIN(( 42.5 - abs(e.latitud)) * 3.14159/180 / 2),2)
                                    + COS( 42.5 * 3.14159/180 ) * COS(abs(e.latitud) *  3.14159/180) 
                                    * POWER(SIN((-8.3 - e.longitud) *  3.14159/180 / 2),2) 
                                ) 
                            ) * 1.609344 as distance, e.idEstacion  
        FROM estaciones e ) t on  t.idEstacion = e2.idEstacion
    WHERE distance < 30.0 order by distance)
WHERE rowNum < 30;
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Is it possible that the datasets you are running against are actually different and the hibernate version includes some text data in the fields?

Comment: No, it seems it was the SQL manager app I was using that was doing the translation; using RazorSQL I also get the given error: Invalid number.

Comment: As in "ORA-01722: invalid number"?  This Oracle error only occurs when you are trying to convert a non-numeric *value* to a numeric one.  Oracle itself has no problem with an implicit conversion (when it is possible)

Comment: well if you check the sql I posted I'm only working with numbers. I even tried replacing the parameters with actual values and I get the same error.

Comment: As you say, you are assuming that all bind variables (which are type free) and values in columns (which are specified as VARCHAR2) contain numbers.  However, the error (if is IS ORA_01722 - you haven't confirmed that) ONLY occurs when a non-numeric is converted to a number.  Are both entity.id and entity2.id NUMBER fields?

Comment: I'd check then to see if any of your `entity.latitude` or `entity.longitude` values are invalid. To find non-numeric latitudes try `SELECT latitude FROM entity WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(latitude, '^\d*\.?\d*$')`. If you don't get any results try the same query but for `longitude` instead of `latitude`.

Comment: I got results for longitude but those are because they have a minus sign since they are negative longitudes

Comment: Exactly how is the negativity expressed?  Can you provide a sample value?

Comment: Also - are both entity.id and entity2.id NUMBER fields?

Comment: Example longitude value: -8.1053312. Ids are indeed numbers.

Comment: And you are certain that the bind variables being passed in are well formatted numbers?

Comment: I edited my original post with an actual SQL Statement I just launched, with no parameters whatsoever. I got the same error.

Comment: How much data do you have in the tables?  Is it low enough to post?

Comment: I somehow fixed it myself by using `to_number(e.latitude, '99999.999999999')`. Thanks for your help!